# Apply middleware in selected environment only

Tags: redux

I'd like to ask how do you enable (or. disable) middleware in, let's say, dev environment only.

I do following:

```
const middlewares = [];

if (__DEV__) {
  middlewares.push(createLogger({
    collapsed: true,
  }));
}

const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(...middlewares));
```

What's your way? Any other ideas?
TY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, that's the correct way to do it - just conditionally put together the list of middlewares you want to apply.  If you're using something like Webpack, you can use the DefinePlugin to globally define strings like `__DEV__`.  In production, that expression will become false, and then the UglifyPlugin would remove it as dead code.

Comment: That's what I do, I let Uglify strip dead code in the end